# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path:PATH is denied

Tags: c#, webclient

For some reason windows is denying my webclient from downloading.

It has permissions to do everything but it is still getting denied. WHY?

**Code:**

```
web.DownloadFile("super epic link", location);
```

**Error:**

```
System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\JANGAJ GAMES\source\repos\html executer\html updater\bin\Debug' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
   at html_updater.Form1.Timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\JANGAJ GAMES\source\repos\html executer\html updater\Form1.cs:line 39
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because IIS cannot access the file. Instead use `Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)` to access the current folder of your app

```
var fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "download.txt");
web.DownloadFile("super epic link", fileName);
```

Comment: Server.MapPath does not exist in current context.

Comment: What do you use ? Web Forms or mvc?

Comment: windows forms if thats what you asked for

Comment: Try running your exe as admin

Comment: Yeah i fixed it. Used downloadasync instead of downloadfile now it works :)